# Netbook freezes with high load on every IO operation

Tags: freeze, cpu-load

I have Acer EEE PC with SSD drives and ubuntu 10.10.
It works fine - most of the time - but after boot or io-intense operation (copying file, installing updates, etc...) load increases to 2, stays for a few minutes and slowly decreases back to 0.5 or so.

How I can confirm source of the problem?
Is it SSD drives, software, drivers, something else?
Any way to fix?

Comment: Old question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the workarounds I already provided in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154097/why-does-wubi-slow-down-or-freeze-when-there-is-heavy-disk-activity/155678#155678):

I noticed awful freezes during IO operations as well. While I can't tell why this is happening, I can offer a workaround. Here's how:

In a terminal, type

`echo "deadline" | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`

Try moving or copying larger ammounts of files again. You should notice a huge difference. If so, make the change permanent by typing in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`, add the following string in between the `""`s:

```
elevator=deadline
```

Save and exit. After that, type in a terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.

FYI: This changes the so-called scheduler to 'deadline'.

**Source**: http://techtitbits.com/2010/04/get-rid-of-freeze-ups-during-disk-io-activity-in-ubuntu/

================================================================================

**Another Possibility** would be to lower dirty_ratio settings.
To test it, type in a terminal:

`sudo bash -c "echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio"`

`sudo bash -c "echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio"`

If this helps, make it permanent by editing your sysctl.conf:

`gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

At the end of the file, add the following lines:

`vm.dirty_ratio=10`

`vm.dirty_background_ratio=5`

Save, close and reboot. Done.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Ubuntu One? I'm experiencing similar problems with U1 after boot.

You can try opening System Monitor (should be under System > Administration) at boot and see if ubuntuone-syncdaemon (or another program) is hogging the hard disk. Or better yet, download a program called iotop, and run it from Terminal right after boot. It'll show which program is responsible for the high I/O wait.